# IPN link not called using sandbox paypal buy button

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

**sandbox paypal merchant account:**

I have created a sandbox paypal button.

I have setup auto redirect to my site after payment is done.

I have turned on IPN notifications.

I have tested that my IPN link is working accordingly using Paypal Developers IPN test tool

**sandbox paypal buyer account:**

I have made a payment (using this sandbox buyer account) by clicking on the above created sandbox button.

But NO IPN notification is sent out. There is NO IPN history as well. Can any one suggest why IPN link is not being called?

Answer (score 0):

i got it, i need to include this in my button html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://myipnurl">
```

although paypal documentation says that this is only required if you need to override default ipn url